# Why isn't any image being displayed in the MS word file generated using PHP?

Tags: php, html, html-to-docx

I am trying to convert a `HTML` content to a `doc` file using PHP. I am following [this](https://www.codexworld.com/convert-html-to-ms-word-document-export-php/) tutorial.

Everything works fine when I export only textual data. But when I try to export an image file, like:

```
<?php
    include_once 'html_to_doc.php';  
    $htmlContent = '<h1 style="text-align: center; color: rgb(50, 91, 205); font-size: 35px;">
    <u>TITLE</u></h1>
    <div style="text-align:center";><table style="background-color:rgb(81, 205, 50); border: 2px solid black;">
    <tr>
        <td style="border: 1px solid black;">
            <img src="/image.jpg" width="150" height="150">
        </td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid black;">
            <img src="/new_image.jpg" width="150" height="150">
        </td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid black; text-align:center">
            <div style="background-color:rgb(148, 76, 17); width:100%; padding:5px; color: white; font-weight: bold;">20/03/2021</div><br>
            <div style="background-color:rgb(20, 104, 104); padding:5px; color: white; font-style: italic; font-weight: bold;">Exclusive</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table></div><br>';
    $htd = new HTML_TO_DOC();
    $htd->createDoc($htmlContent, "word_file",1);
?>
```

There's a cross (**X**) mark in place of the image, in the `doc` file, even when the image url is correct. Where am I going wrong? Please help me.

When I try to print the image directory

```
    echo __DIR__.'/image.jpg';
```

and go to the link, the image shows. That means the image url is correct. So why isn't it being rendered in my word file?

Comment: what do you think `/image.jpg` actually means ?

Comment: Does this HTML work if you use it directly in a web page? That would be a good test to begin with. I note you've forgotten the quote marks at the end of each time you've declared a `src` for the images. So that's one obvious problem (there may be others). Always double-check and debug your work initially.

Comment: Both the script and the image are in the root directory

Comment: You were missing a double quote after `src="/image.jpg` before you edited your question, but even with it, I'm not sure you will get the image in the word document. Have a look at [Convert your images
to base64](https://www.base64-image.de/).

Comment: @KIKOSoftware oh sorry, that was a typing mistake. I have also tried the `Base64` equivalent of the image, it still doesn't show in the file.

Comment: `that was a typing mistake`...always copy/paste your code into Stackoverflow, to avoid this kind of thing. Then we don't get distracted which stuff which isn't an issue in the real code.

Comment: Where is the image file located in your filesystem, relative to the PHP script you're executing this from?

Comment: P.S. I haven't looked in detail but this https://github.com/Korchy/html_to_doc seems to be a very similar concept, and, from looking at the demo they've provided, appears to support use of images.

Comment: @ADyson both the image and the script are inside `C:\xampp\htdocs`

Comment: Ok. Like I  said...did you test this HTML snippet in a HTML document, independently? Does it find the image then?

Comment: @ADyson, yes, when I execute the HTML code independently, the images show

Comment: I don't understand, why you to get image since "/image.jpg" into src ? Because if image was in same folder you write "./image.jpg", or if doesn't work you try complete path into src="completePath/image.jpg".